# Problem while calling servlet using Jetty

Tags: gwt, jetty, web.xml, embedded-jetty

I installed jetty on my ubuntu and uploaded my webapplication in webapps folder of jetty but

when i am trying to call my servlet using $ajax

```
$("#signIn").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:8090/myapp/myappmodule/getToken",
          contentType: "text/html",
      success: function(msg) {
    window.open(msg);
      }
    });
```

});

but it gives me following message :

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /myapp/myappmodule/getToken. Reason:

NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: You need to provide more details if you want to get a helpful answer. Things you should do: (1) Look at the jetty logs, and copy the relevant sections (2) Try browsing to "http://localhost:8090/". which do you get? (3) Try "http://localhost:8090/myapp/" what do you get? (4) What do the logs say for the last 2 tests?     You also need to tell us the name of your application, and how it was built.